# How to deserialize JSON with private constructor and interfaces as Builder?

Tags: java, json, jackson, builder

I've searched the internet for something to similar to what I'm doing, but haven't found anything. I'm using interfaces in Java 8 to create a Builder pattern, like so:

```
public class UrlImmutable {
   public final String parentUrl;
   public final Double parentUrlSentiment;
   public final Set<String> childUrls;
   public final boolean isParentVendorUrl;
   public final Map<TagClassification, Set<String>> parentUrlArticleTags;

private UrlImmutable(String parentUrl, Double parentUrlSentiment, Set<String> childUrls, boolean isParentVendorUrl, 
        Map<TagClassification, Set<String>> parentUrlArticleTags ) {
    super();
    this.parentUrl = parentUrl;
    this.parentUrlSentiment = parentUrlSentiment;
    this.childUrls = childUrls;
    this.isParentVendorUrl = isParentVendorUrl;
    this.parentUrlArticleTags = parentUrlArticleTags;
}

/** Our Interfaces for the Builder **/
public interface ParentUrlBuilder {
    ParentUrlSentimentBuilder parentUrl(String parentUrl);
}
public interface ParentUrlSentimentBuilder {
    ChildUrlBuilder parentUrlSentiment(Double parentUrlSentiment);
}
public interface ChildUrlBuilder {
    IsVendorUrlBuilder childUrls(Set<String> childUrls);
}
public interface IsVendorUrlBuilder {
    ParentUrlArticleTagsBuilder isParentVendorUrl(boolean isParentVendorUrl);
}
public interface ParentUrlArticleTagsBuilder {
    UrlImmutable parentUrlArticleTags(Map<TagClassification,Set<String>> parentUrlArticleTags);
}

public static ParentUrlBuilder discoveredUrl() {
    return parentUrl -> parentUrlSentiment -> childUrls -> isParentVendorUrl ->  parentUrlArticleTags -> 
    new UrlImmutable(parentUrl, parentUrlSentiment, childUrls, isParentVendorUrl, parentUrlArticleTags);
}
```

}

And to construct this object, we do this:

```
UrlImmutable url = 
    UrlImmutable()
        .parentUrl("http://www.google.com")
        .parentUrlSentiment(10.5)
        .childUrls(childUrls)
        .isParentVendorUrl(true)
        .parentUrlArticleTags(parentUrlArticleTags);
```

I can't seem to find the right combination of annotations for this. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Why does the constructor have to be private? A Builder is supposed to be a convenient way of constructing a complex object, not the mandatory way. On top of this json issue, you are going to run into other hassles down the road because your POJO does not conform to the Java bean convention. I hope you find it worth it.

Comment: Well, it wasn't my decision - it's what the architect likes...

Comment: Why don't you add the getInstance method which internally calls the constructor, the way singleton pattern does but don't return single instance, return new instance every time, Call will look this:UrlImmutable url = 
    getInstance()
        .parentUrl("http://www.google.com")
        .parentUrlSentiment(10.5)

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, but how would that solve my problem? Can you give me an example?

Comment: This code example really smells to me. The `public final String parentUrl; ...` makes no sense, a member public and final, really ?

Comment: This article does the same thing. Maybe that's where my lead got the idea from? http://benjiweber.co.uk/blog/2014/11/02/builder-pattern-with-java-8-lambdas/

Comment: IMHO this article is about `How to use Java Lambdas for anything else that it wasn't made for`. I think in your case the Builder pattern, yes, it is applicable and makes sense (if not, you end in constructors with long args list). As JSON libs are mostly running on POJO's (with getter+setter) out of the box, in this case you are on your own.

Comment: But I thought somehow Jackson for jdk8 would support lambdas like this?